# How can i broadcast UDP packet to the browser

Tags: udp, webrtc, broadcast

I am beginner level.
I try to broadcast data to the browsers in local area ( Same router by sending . . . 255 ).

I should implement the real time streaming service to the local level browsers.
But it will occur high traffic when the client browsers is increased.

To broadcast data, it seems to need UDP protocol.
But web browser base on TCP.
So i investigated the webRTC that is based on UDP.
But i don't really know how to use this.
Is it possible to broadcast the data to the web browser like chrome in local area ?
If not, why it is impossible to implement ? just for hazard of DDOS ? How can i solve this high traffic problem ?

( It really occur high traffic when each clients respond to every data from server (TCP) or the server send same data to the every client amount to number of clients (not broadcasting). 
I just want to implement that the server just send one broadcasting datagram packet to the local area and each clients in local level receive same one data from the server but not respond to that. )

Comment: You may be able to do this through a data channel in WebRTC. However, on your server side, create a peerconnection that can forward your data(using one of the many gateways or the native API).

Comment: I think the data channel is also peer-to-peer connection. Can this let one packet go every client in local area ?

Comment: That is not really possible with anything WebRTC provides, you will have to have numerous connections for each peer. You cannot broadcast UDP like that with out individual connections to each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- From a web app (not a modified web browser itself), you cannot create nor manipulate raw (UDP/TCP) sockets.The sandboxing and other mechanisms won't let you.
- with webRTC, you will need to make an handshake, and use ICE.
  => You cannot push to a peer knowing only his IP/port
  => You have to have the receiver accept and acknowledge the transfer
- you might have more change with WebSockets, but that requires additional mechanisms as well and not all parties will be able to support web socket (or accept the upgrade from http to WS).

For illustration purpose, you can see the work of Jess on a web-based bit torrent. He has exactly the same problems. https://github.com/feross/webtorrent

Comment: Ah.. is webtorrent useful for real time video streaming service ?

Comment: could be, but I doubt it would be for real-time media, more for pre-recorded media streaming. I just wanted to point out that, even though he applies to a different problem, jeross has the same underlying problem. He would also need raw sockets to support bit torrent, and it is not possible in a browser.